# Equation mode, labelling equations

Tags: equations

I have the following

```
\[K^{-1}\left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_ny_n\right\|
   \leq \left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_nx_n\right\|
   \leq K\left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_ny_n\right\| (\dagger)\]
```

But the dagger doesn't appear at the right hand end of the page. How can I Get it so that it does appear on the end of the page? the `\hfill` command doesn't seem to work.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You are probably looking for `\tag{$\dagger$}` inside the environment `equation` with package `amsmath` loaded.

Comment: But note that the tag goes on the same side as the equation number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the `tag` macro, which is provided by the `amsmath` package, to place the dagger symbol. I further suggest you create a dedicated LaTeX macro -- e.g., with the help of the `mathtools` package -- named `\norm`. This will make your code more readable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads 'amsmath' package automatically
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\[
     K^{-1}\norm[\bigg]{\sum_{n=1}^N a_ny_n}
     \leq  \norm[\bigg]{\sum_{n=1}^N a_nx_n}
     \leq K\norm[\bigg]{\sum_{n=1}^N a_ny_n}
  \tag{$\dagger$}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give the required result:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\begin{document}  
\[K^{-1}\left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_ny_n\right\|  
   \leq \left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_nx_n\right\|  
   \leq K\left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_ny_n\right\| \eqno{(\dagger)}\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]