# Flushing right in math mode

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
$$\{(x,y)\,|\,Ax+By+Cz=0\} = L$$ \begin{flushright}\dag \end{flushright}[1]
```

I am trying to align the dagger so it is flushed to the right but on the same line as the equation. When i insert `\begin{flushright}\dag \end{flushright}`inside $$ I get a compiling error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Off-topic: Please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for why one shouldn't use `$$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate display-math mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equation mode, labelling equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239532/equation-mode-labelling-equations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution uses the `\tag*` macro (provided by the `amsmath` package) to accomplish your objective.

[image]

Aside: The thick vertical lines at the left and right-hand edges of the image indicate the dimensions of the text block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \tag* macro
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\[
\bigl\{ (x,y) \bigm| Ax+By+Cz=0 \bigr\} = L \tag*{$\dagger$}
\]
\end{document}
```